# Trying to display contents of a list in a console app with WriteLine

Tags: c#, wcf

I am trying to display contents of a list in a console app with WriteLine. I am using the following code:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using TestCLient.ClientTransactionsServiceReference;

    namespace TestCLient
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                ClientTransactionsServiceClient client = new ClientTransactionsServiceClient();
                List<ClientTransactions> ct = client.GetClientTransactions("9999");
                ct.ForEach(i => Console.Write(i));
                Console.Read();
            }
         }
    }
```

I am getting the following output:

[image: Output Screenshot]

When I debug, my list (ct) shows that it contains the fields I want displayed. see the following screenshot:

[image: Debug screenshot]

I have searched many sources including Stack to get the line of code I'm using to write my list. I'm new to programming and would greatly appreciate your assistance.

Thanks

Comment: you have to write ClientTransactions's some properties. not the object, like i.something

Comment: Can you upload a bigger screenshot? We can hardly see anything. Most probably, you'll need to write something like `Console.WriteLine(i.Property1 +" "+ i.Property2)` to show the actual contents

Comment: @JuliánUrbano SO re-sizes the image to fit on the thread. Right Click > View Image | Open In New Tab :p

Comment: I think you can piece the problem together from the bits of hints everyone gave you ;)

Comment: @ByteBlast ah! I thought it was just that because the image had no link. #noobhere

Comment: why is everytone downvoting all the answers here?

Comment: @JuliánUrbano fixed. created an hyperlink.

Comment: Thanks all for your assistance her is my working solution:ct.ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine(i.AccountID + " " + i.FirstName + " " + i.LastName + " " +
                i.DOB + " " + i.EncryptedSSN + " " + i.Address + " " + i.City + " " + i.State + " " +
                i.Zip + " " + i.LogDateTime + " " + i.TranID));
            Console.Read();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Console.Write` is implicitly calling `ToString()` on the object you are trying to print in the Console.  Because your type does not override `ToString()` the text being returned is a result of the default implementation of `ToString()` defined by the `Object` class (from which all types derive from).

Rather than passing `i` as an argument to `Console.Write` pass `i.NameOfThePropertyYouWantToOutput`.

Answer (score 1):

You either print out each property you need.. Or better yet, override the `ToString()` method and call that like in the following code :

`ct.ForEach(i => Console.Write(i.ToString()));`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are outputting an instance of `ClientTransactions`, you need to specify how to render the information on the console. You can either output one or more properties of this instance, or override the `ToString()` method.

Answer (score -1):

You try to parse your object into a string.

If you want to display correctly your object into the console you need to display a member of your client object.

```
ct.ForEach(i => Console.Write(i.Name )); // exemple
            Console.Read();
```